# c# Regex to match all Sri Lankan phone numbers

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I didn't find any on google on the *regex expression* for *Sri Lankan phone numbers*;
The formats are:

1. `775645645` (**9** digits)
2. `0775645645` (**10** digits)
3. `+94775645645`

It should start with **7** or **0** or **+94**. Can anyone help me with this.
Appreciate your solutions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: `^7|0|(?:\+94)[0-9]{9,10}$`

Comment: This is a cool [https://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3](https://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3) site, which is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's build the `pattern`:

```
 ^            - anchor (string start)
 7|0|(?:\+94) - either 7 or 0 or +94
[0-9]{9,10}   - from 9 up and including to 10 digits (chars on [0-9] range)
 $            - anchor (string end)
```

So we have

```
  string pattern = @"^(?:7|0|(?:\+94))[0-9]{9,10}$";
```

Tests:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "775645645",
  "0775645645",
  "+94775645645",
  "123456669",
  "1234566698888",
  "+941234566698888",
  "+94123456"
};

string pattern = @"^(?:7|0|(?:\+94))[0-9]{9,10}$";

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(item => $"{item,-20} : {(Regex.IsMatch(item, pattern) ? "Matched" : "Not")}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
775645645            : Matched
0775645645           : Matched
+94775645645         : Matched
123456669            : Not
1234566698888        : Not
+941234566698888     : Not
+94123456            : Not
```

Comment: i tried to use this for angular +94775645645 this give me not matching state. if i deduct one number it show as valid. i think language is not matter regex is same for everyware right? here is my code "Validators.pattern('^7|0|(?:\\+94)[0-9]{9,10}$')"

Comment: @Sahan Pasindu Nirmal: could you, please, turn the *comment* to a *question*? Mark it with *Angular* tag and provide not just `Validators.pattern('^7|0|(?:\\+94)[0-9]{9,10}$')` but the context (how do you apply the validator on the input data)?

Comment: in angular we can specify pattern validation using this method "Validators.pattern" full code like this this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      userName: [
        null, Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])
      ],

Comment: This is a example i can place any patter which i want. but if i use +94712345678 like this that give me error like pattern not valid, how ever when i enter with +947 and more seven number that give me it is valid number, but it is wrong it must be contain +947 with more 8 numbers.

Comment: i cannot explain this within a comment section in here, any place we can talk in more details? thank you :)

Comment: @Sahan Pasindu Nirmal: I see, that's why I suggest to put it as *question* on *Stack Overflow*: the very place you can provide necessary details (relevant code, test cases etc.) and have an auditory which can help you.

Comment: You missed parentheses around the whole regex, as is, it matches any string that begins with `7` or any string that contains a `0` any where, see: https://regex101.com/r/osHPJF/1

Comment: @Toto: I see, nice catch! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 String regexPhoneNumber = "^(?:0|94|\\+94)?(?:(11|21|23|24|25|26|27|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|41|45|47|51|52|54|55|57|63|65|66|67|81|912)(0|2|3|4|5|7|9)|7(0|1|2|5|6|7|8)\\d)\\d{6}$";
```

Valid phone number Types:-

- 0771234567
- 771234567
- +94771234567
- 94771234567
- 0111234567(local codes)

Comment: You should use character classes instead of these long alternations, for example `[0-25-8]` instead of `(0|1|2|5|6|7|8)`

Answer (score 0):

Updated to newly assigned mobile providers:

```
String regexPhoneNumber = "^(?:0|94|\\+94)?(?:(11|21|23|24|25|26|27|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|41|45|47|51|52|54|55|57|63|65|66|67|81|912)(0|2|3|4|5|7|9)|7(0|1|2|4|5|6|7|8)\\d)\\d{6}$";
```